# Android listview scroll is not smooth,when I load many bitmaps

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, bitmap

Recently I encounter a strange problem,when I use the github library named Universal-Image-Loader.Each of my listview items has at most three imageview.when I scroll the listview to display image,the listview is so nonfluency.I read the source codes,I find it loads bitmap from background thread and then uses handler to post the bitmap to ui thread.So I want to know whether because I load many bitmaps and post lots of messages to ui thread,then it causes the listview is non fluency.

```
List<String> babySnapImgUrls = shopBean.babySnapImgUrls;
if (babySnapImgUrls != null) {
    int size = Math.min(babySnapImgUrls.size(), 3);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        final ImageView snapView = mViewHolder.snapViews[i];
        if(snapView.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE)
            snapView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //snapView.setImageDrawable(null); //                Object url = mViewHolder.snapImageViewAwares[i].getWrappedView().getTag(); //       String urlStr = ""; //                if(url != null){ //              urlStr = url.toString(); //                }
        //if(!babySnapImgUrls.get(i).equals(urlStr)) {
            mViewHolder.snapImageViewAwares[i].getWrappedView().setTag(babySnapImgUrls.get(i));
           // Log.e("koudai",ImageLoader.getInstance().)
            displayImage(babySnapImgUrls.get(i), mViewHolder.snapImageViewAwares[i],
                    KoudaiDisplayImageOptions.DEFAULT_DISPLAY_IMAGE_OPTIONS);
        //}
    }
    for (int i = size; i < 3; i++) {
        if(mViewHolder.snapViews[i].getVisibility() != View.INVISIBLE)
            mViewHolder.snapViews[i].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        ImageLoader.getInstance().cancelDisplayTask(mViewHolder.snapImageViewAwares[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should really post some code here, probably the code of your adapter.

Comment: I have post some codes of my adapter,but I don't do other things,except I call the method which comes from libary.

Comment: Do you recycle your views in the adapter?

Comment: No,I just load bitmap for imageview,each of my listview items has three imageview widgets.

Comment: You should defenitly recycle your views, that should improve the performance of your scrolling. Bitmaps are quite heavy objects to display.

Comment: I have used the viewholder method advised by google to recycle imageviews

Comment: I wanna load many Images From Drawable to Grid view and can't use Universal-Image-Loader cause it load images from web. I have the same problem and still unsolved. if you get the answer let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Loading Bitmaps in ListView requires a correct approach. I was having the same problem, and I found this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) a bit helpful.

If none of the best practices works, then the last resort to handle scroll lagging is to reduce the size (or quality) of the Bitmap. I was using [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) to load and resize images. After that, I finally got a smooth scroll.